# How to change name of API in WSO2 API Manger 1.8

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I developed API in  WSO2 API manager names 'sample' ,Its working fine .Now i want to change the name of API with some valid name ,Is there any way to do this .Any help ?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know you cannot change API name in WSO2 API Manager. You would need to recreate the API with a new name. You can probably use Swagger export and import to make the migration easier.

Answer (score 0):

Following [Editing and Deleting APIs](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM170/Editing+and+Deleting+APIs), i tried to change the name of the api between the -api- tag, which is slightly different in the actual WSO2 API Manager Version (1.9.1), but it had no effect at all.

Also if you check the REST resources from [Publisher APIs](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM180/Publisher+APIs#PublisherAPIs-UpdateAPI), in the Update API operation.
It has the following behavior 
"***Update API***: Parameters are same as in Add API except that action=updateAPI and you can only update the following parameters: visibility, t humbUrl, description, tags, endpointType, endpoint_config (can change the endpoint URL etc,) http_checked, https_checked, wsdl, wadl, tier, tiersCollection and can also add new resources. See example below."  So it's not possible in this way either.

**Workaround:**

Go to API Publisher, find the API you want to change the name of, then press on Edit, after that, under *Design* tab, in the section *General Details* select the *Edit Source* button.
There you will see the API configuration in a JSON format, copy that config.
Create a new API with New_Name, then go to *Edit Source* and paste the configuration.

My conclusion is that with WSO2 API Manager Version 1.9.1 it's not possible to change the API's Name after it's published, not directly, but there are some workarounds to do if you really need to do the job.

Answer (score 0):

Until now 22/05/2020 Api Manager WSO2 Still not support rename API. The only way is create a new one.